# Discord - showing member join position with specified number

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to show you which number of users I entered in the argument is the order of joining the server. Like = when i use `.join 1`  I want to show the 1st member join in to the server. I use

```
let arr = message.guild.members.filter(a => !a.user.bot).array().sort((b, a) => b.joinedTimestamp - a.joinedTimestamp) 
let map = arr.indexOf(sesmi) + 1
```

this command for showing joing position but im so confused how can i do as i said?

Comment: So what`s the problem you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
// if the first argument is not a number (this message is kind of bad so you can change it)
if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply('you must specify what number user you want to get!')

const members = message.guild.members.cache
  .filter(member => !member.user.bot)
  // sorted is a member on Discord's utility class Collection that doesn't modify the original collection
  .sorted((a, b) => a.joinedTimestamp - b.joinedTimestamp)
  .array()

// the number user to get
const n = Number(args[0])
// if there are not enough members
if (n > members.length) {
  // You only really need this if there is ever going to be only 1 member in the server
  // and if you care about grammar. You could also just do
  // return message.reply(`there are only ${members.length} members!`)
  const plural = members.length !== 1
  return message.reply(`there ${plural ? 'are' : 'is'} only ${members.length} member${plural ? 's' : ''}!`)
}
message.channel.send(members[n - 1].user.tag)
```

I'm assuming `args` will be an array of strings with the arguments passed into the command (e.g. `.join 1` will have the `args` `['1']`.